# Connection was reset error when installing magento in localhost

Tags: php, magento-1.7, magento

Finally after much research when I couldn't get anything, I'm posting here. I'm trying to install magento on wamp server version 2.2d. I extracted the Magento CE 1.7.0 to 'magento' folder in c:\wamp\www. I checked the dependencies and they are all compliant. When I try to access magento through localhost/magento/, the url changes and I get a Connection was reset error.

How to solve this error. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by URL changes?

Comment: Try to use http://open-server.ru/ instead. I installed CE 1.7-1.7.0.2 many times on php 5.3.10+ on open server, never had any problem.

Answer (score 0):

some times we get error from our server configuration .
so pls switch to xmapp server and enable the url rewriting .
and plase dont check checkbox at install time of magento "base url validation".
i m also new with magento . i m also using the magento 1.7